# Get content from JSON using jQuery Mobile

Tags: php, json, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to figure out how to retrieve simple html content using JSON in a jQuery Mobile.

Here is how I have done so far:

matchinfo.php:

```
$str = '<h2>This is a test</h2><p>What is going on here?</p>';

echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' .json_encode($str). ')';
```

And here is how I try to recieve it:

```
$(document).on('pageshow', function (){

    $.mobile.loading('show');
    $.getJSON("http://mypage.com/matchinfo.php", function (result){
        $("#pageName").html(result.html);
    });

    $('#pageName').content('refresh');
    $.mobile.loading('hide');

});
```

The spinner just keeps loading! I am able to do this with listview, but here I just want to get some content!?

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Your code is looking for a key called `html` but your data is just a flat string. `json_encode(array('html' => $str));`

Comment: shouldnt you have a `?callback=someCallback` in the url ?

Comment: @DaveRandom - Just perfect... didn't see that :-) Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You're not outputting JSON, you're outputting JSONp. You probably shouldn't use `getJSON` for that, JSONp isn't supposed to work with XMLHTTPRequest (AJAX).

`getJSON` is shorthand for:

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery `$.get` instead of `$.getJSON`

```
$.get('http://mypage.com/matchinfo.php', function(result) {
    $('#pageName').html(result);
});
```

Also notice that in the `.html()` function you just need to pass `result` instead of `result.html`